# Showing a hidden datatable with Jquery breaks CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

EDIT: SOLVED. When the page originally loads the datatable is formed using the css files as laid out. However when it was calling the javscript it was rebuilding the datatable and ignoring any CSS files I had referenced. As such it was automatically shrinking the table to match the size of  the text. This was avoided by setting bAutoWidth = false in the actual creation of the datatable.

Thanks to everyone who helped!.

so I have a datatable as follows.

```
   <div class="datatable" style="display:none;">
            <div class="row">
                <table class="display" id="testtable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>First column</th>
                            <th>Second</th>
                            <th>Third</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="selectable">                           
                                <tr class="gradeU">
                                    <td align="left">First column info</td>
                                    <td align="left">second</td>
                                    <td>Third</td>
                                </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
```

So the above is the datatable, as you can see the table itself is hidden as I only want to show it when a user hovers over a button. When the user hovers over the button the following code is called from a function.

```
   $(".datatable").show();
```

This works, however it breaks the CSS. The datatable becomes very squashed and is only about one quarter the width it should be. I have tried setting the width to be bigger in the function that is called however no luck. I know it has something to do with the following code

```
     style="display:none;"
```

as once I take this out the table displays fine however I need it hidden until the function is called.

I have tried the usual $(element).style.visibilty but nothing seems to make a difference, the table stubbornly refuses to go to its correct size. Any help is greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.

EDIT: Below is the CSS of the table and TD

```
   table.display {
margin: 10px;
padding: 5px;
clear: both;
width: 98%;
overflow: auto;
/*    text-align: center;*/
height: auto;

    }

    table.display td {
        padding: 5px 5px;
     }

    table.display td.center {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

EDIT: I have uploaded 2 images to show the differences between the tables.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/840/correecttable.png/

That is the table when it is not hidden.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/822/incorrecttable.png/

That is the table when it is hidden and then shown using jQuery.

Comment: how does it look if you use: style="display:block"? is it messed up immediately?

Comment: Could you show us the css as well please? Because that is not normal behaviour, if you remove the display:none; does it looks as you'd expect it would?

Comment: Yeah, as soon as the table shows it shows in the wrong format, in this case not as wide as it should be. css('display,'block') makes no difference.

Comment: Updated question with the tables CSS.

Comment: Also Danny, yes it does. Once the display:none is removed the table is displayed exactly as it should be.

Comment: what is the css for .datatable? maybe add a fiddle of it so we can replicate the issue

Comment: looks more like the styles aren't being added to the cells, what css have you got for the td's?

Comment: Never really used Fiddle much so I am not really sure but the datatable is being called using a Datatable js class. Is there a way to include it in the fiddle?

Comment: in your photo there is something defining the width of the description tab.. but in your CSS i cannot see that

Comment: Update this fiddle with the relevant parts.. http://jsfiddle.net/txSED/5/ I'd leave the data as that as it's just an example set of data

Comment: Updated it with most of the CSS there.

Comment: Just edited the question with the solution there Danny. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: glad it helped! sorry got called away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page originally loads the datatable is formed using the css files as laid out. However when it was calling the javscript it was rebuilding the datatable and ignoring any CSS files I had referenced. As such it was automatically shrinking the table to match the size of the text. This was avoided by setting bAutoWidth = false in the actual creation of the datatable.

Thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 5):

the CSS is broken because jQuery's `.show()` and `.hide()` functions just switches between `display: none` and `display: block`(or `display: inline`), but the default value of `display` property of `<table>` element is `display: table` and not `display: block`, so instead of using `$(".datatable").show();` and `$(".datatable").hide();` use the following:

```
$(".datatable").css({'display': 'none'});  // to hide the table, here you can
                                           //  still use jQuery's .hide()
$(".datatable").css({'display': 'table'}); // to show the table
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either. Same problem as above.

Comment: @Chaney the problem could relate to the other elements of page, can you please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example with more code to reproduce the situation and see the relation between other elements?

Comment: Thanks Haynar, I got it fixed and put solution into my answer. Thanks for the help though!.

Comment: I don't speak english, but your response is amazing.. That resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here´s a part of jquery´s docu of the method .show():

> With no parameters, the .show() method is the simplest way to display
>   an element:
>
> `$('.target').show();`
>
> The matched elements will be revealed immediately, with no animation.
>   This is roughly equivalent to calling .css('display', 'block')

So show sets your element to display:block and this is probably how it looks in display:block.

Here is a [full description of .show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Probably you just have to edit the table´s css attributes in a way that makes it look nice on display:bock.

Comment: Tried that however the problem with that is the table can be quite large and this leaves a large blank space in the page where the table should be.

Comment: ah i see, i will cleanup my answer! ;)

Comment: It also mentions however, "except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially." I may be misinterpreting it here but I would have thought that meant it restored its original CSS. I could be wrong though :)

Comment: I think it means that it will go back to your display: none;

Comment: Thanks Konstantin, I got it fixed and put solution into my answer. Thanks for the help though!.